# How to implement an Onboarding screen (Swipe Screen) after a Splash Screen while running an app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, merge, splash-screen

I've created a **Splash Screen** and an **Onboarding (Swipe Screen)**. Now I want to **link** these two in a way that after the Splash Screen my Onboarding screen should appear.

> I have imported the Onboarding project via Source code and converted it into a Library. Using dependencies I've used this Library in my current project.i.e Splash Screen. Now in my current project, I've used Explicit Intent.

`Handler handler = new Handler(); handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, IntroActivity.class); startActivity(intent); finish(); } },2500);`

Comment: use `startActivity()` to navigate to OnBoarding Activity.

Comment: so what's the issue you are facing? Also post some code..

Comment: I have imported the Onboarding project via Source code and converted it into a Library. Using dependencies I've used this Library in my current project.i.e Splash Screen. Now in my current project, I've used Explicit Intent.

Comment: `Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },2500);`

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Code is unreadable in comments. Also, comments may or may not be shown initially, or in any order. See also [ask].